# Thickness definition for ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

How is the thickness defined in `ParametricPlot3D`?  For 2D plots, the thickness "is given as a fraction of the horizontal plot range," but how does that work in 3D for the following example?  Also, it doesn't seem that `AbsoluteThickness` works.

```
Moebius[R_, a_, b_] := {(R + a Cos[b/2]) Cos[b], (R + a Cos[b/2]) Sin[b], a Sin[b/2]}

MBand = ParametricPlot3D[Moebius[5, a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> {20, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
  PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[{Thickness[1], Opacity[0.5]}]]
```

Comment: Welcome! For info on formatting, please take a look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 5):

The three argument form of `ParametricPlot3D`

> [image]

i.e, it produces a number of surface polygons.

The directive `Thickness` applies to `Line`s. You can specify the thickness of mesh lines, polygon edges or boundary lines.

**Applying `Thickness` to polygon edges using `EdgeForm` in `PlotStyle`:**

```
ParametricPlot3D[Moebius[5, a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotPoints -> {5, 10},
 PlotStyle -> EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[.005], Opacity[0.5]}]]
```

[image]

**Applying `Thickness` to mesh lines using  `MeshStyle`:**

```
ParametricPlot3D[Moebius[5, a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotPoints -> {20, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All,
 Mesh -> {5, 10}, MeshStyle -> {Directive[{Red, Thickness[.005]}], 
   Directive[{Blue, Thickness[.01]}]}]
```

[image]

**Applying `Thickness` to boundary lines using  `BoundaryStyle`:**

```
ParametricPlot3D[Moebius[5, a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotPoints -> {20, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> None,  BoundaryStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**AbsoluteThickness versus Thickness:**

```
Animate[Row[
  ParametricPlot3D[Moebius[5, a, b], {a, -1, 1}, {b, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     ImageSize -> t,
     PlotPoints -> {20, 100}, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
     Mesh -> None, Axes -> False, Boxed -> False,
     PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", PlotLabel -> Style[#, 14, "Panel"],
     BoundaryStyle -> Directive[{Red, #}]] & /@ {AbsoluteThickness[3],
     Thickness[.01]}, Spacer[5]],
 {t, {150, 300,600}},  Paneled -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: So what is horizontal plot range in 3d case?

Comment: @Kuba, good question. Probably the the range of the first axes; but ... your guess is as good as mine:)

Comment: @kguler Thanks for the detailed response.  It appears that a thickness specification in ParametricPlot3D is absolute, i.e. Thickness[2] yields a thickness of 2 units. So, in the following example, you can see that the thickness of 0.5 at x=y=-2 corresponds to the distance between the horizontal lines drawn 0.5 units apart.

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{x, y, (2*x*y)/(x^2 + y^2)},}, {x, -2, 
   2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.5]], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, -2, 1.25}, {x, -2, 2}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{x, -2, 0.75}, {x, -2, 2}]]

Comment: Russell, actually,  i think, your example shows that thickness is not absolute, because "it is _not_  independent of the image size". The absolute thickness is measured in units of printer's points and it does not change when you resize the image.