# Controlling line thickness in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I want to control the thickness of the line in `ParametricPlot3D`. I read the answer in
[Thickness definition for ParametricPlot3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65318/thickness-definition-for-parametricplot3d) but it does not solve the problem. In the example below,

`thickness = 3.0;ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[thickness]]`

the thickness changes abruptly from something very thin (for my taste) to something very thick (for my taste) by changing `thickness` from `3.0` to `3.1`. Thickness seems to increase smoothly only above 3 or so. Is it possible to control the line thickness of thinner lines in a smooth way?

[Edited after the original posting] A new observation, when using `\PlotStyle->Dashed` the line thickness behaves as expected, it increases continuously from 0 up.

Comment: This is a [problem that has been found before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152709/problem-with-thickness-in-3d-plots)... Unfortunately, I know of no solution.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think it's a duplicate. Do you agree?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Okay, I've just marked it as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the previous discussion, I had missed it.